# java sql syntax error select

Tags: java, sql, select

So i have this code which should supply me with the id of a row.

```
public int getIdSala(Connection conn, String t) {
    try {
        String query = "Select id_sala from sala where nume = ?";

        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, t);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        id = rs.getInt("Id_sala");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQLserver version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What database? What JDBC driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do `st.executeQuery(query)` but just `st.executeQuery()`

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thank you very much for your time. I`m new to java sql :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the query in twice.

```
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `st.executeQuery();` instead of `st.executeQuery(query)`

here is [example](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/TwicePreparedStatement.shtml)